# Create a file listing applications, processes, and services running and those scheduled to run on OSX on boot

Tags: security, macos, service, startup

I'm looking for a script or some advice on how to write a script that can create a file listing all of the processes that run when my system boots.  I suspect that this goes beyond just waiting till the boot process is complete and enumerating the applications and services that are currently running.

The idea is to create a file listing all things that ran, are running, or will run and compare that file to a new one on each boot so I can raise an alert when something has changed.

Comment: One fairly crude trick might be to [enable process accounting](http://www.cites.illinois.edu/security/by_os/osxadv.html). I'm not sure how early at boot it gets enabled, so it'll miss some early startup, but might provide good data that might otherwise be difficult to find. I hope you can find something better. :)